# Running QT Creator's project .exe gives 0xc000007b error

Tags: c++, qt

I just started to learn QT Creator for a school project. my program runs fine in QT Creator

QT: 5.6.0 (MSVC 2015)
QT Creator 3.

but running the exe file outside of the IDE I get

```
"The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). click ok to close application."
```

After googling around, this is not an issue of the app needing to be deployed (at least I think?) but an issue of mixing 32/64 bit libraries (which I don't know how I am only using QT stuff in my project)

So I was able to find out that I can use Dependency Walker to see what can be going wrong

After I run it, I get more issues that say errors detected check log file but I do get back results which I can't tell if there is any info on mixed 32/64 bit libs but i do get a lot of

```
"Error opening file. The system cannot find the file specified (2)
```

so here are the files that gave that error message

```
API-MS-WIN-CORE-APIQUERY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-APPCOMPAT-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-APPINIT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-ATOMS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L1-1-0
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-MIDLPROXYSTUB-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COMM-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CONSOLE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CONSOLE-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CRT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CRT-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DATETIME-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DATETIME-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DEBUG-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DELAYLOAD-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-ENCLAVE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-ERRORHANDLING-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-ERRORHANDLING-L1-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FIBERS-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FIBERS-L2-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L1-2-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L1-2-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L2-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L2-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-HANDLE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-HEAP-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-HEAP-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-HEAP-OBSOLETE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-INTERLOCKED-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-IO-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-JOB-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-JOB-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-LEGACY-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-LEGACY-L1-1-4.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-PRIVATE-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LARGEINTEGER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LIBRARYLOADER-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LIBRARYLOADER-L1-2-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LIBRARYLOADER-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-L1-2-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-L1-2-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-OBSOLETE-L1-3-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-MEMORY-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-MISC-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-NAMEDPIPE-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-NAMEDPIPE-L1-2-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-NAMESPACE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-NORMALIZATION-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PATH-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PERFCOUNTERS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PRIVATEPROFILE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSENVIRONMENT-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSSNAPSHOT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTHREADS-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTHREADS-L1-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTOPOLOGY-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROFILE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PSAPI-ANSI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PSAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PSM-KEY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-QUIRKS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REALTIME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRY-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRYUSERSPECIFIC-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-RTLSUPPORT-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SHLWAPI-LEGACY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SHLWAPI-OBSOLETE-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SIDEBYSIDE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-STRING-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-STRING-L2-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-STRING-OBSOLETE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-STRINGANSI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYNCH-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYNCH-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYNCH-L1-2-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSINFO-L1-2-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSINFO-L1-2-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSTEMTOPOLOGY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-THREADPOOL-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-THREADPOOL-LEGACY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-THREADPOOL-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-TIMEZONE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-URL-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-UTIL-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-VERSION-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-VERSIONANSI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINDOWSERRORREPORTING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WOW64-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WOW64-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-XSTATE-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-CONVERT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-ENVIRONMENT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-FILESYSTEM-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-HEAP-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-LOCALE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-MATH-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-MULTIBYTE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-RUNTIME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-STDIO-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-TIME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-UTILITY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DEVICES-CONFIG-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-CLASSICPROVIDER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-CONSUMER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-CONTROLLER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-OBSOLETE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-PROVIDER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-APPCONTAINER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-AUDIT-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-BASE-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-BASE-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-SDDL-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-CORE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-CORE-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-MANAGEMENT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-MANAGEMENT-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-0
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-WINSVC-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHELL-SHELLCOM-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHELL-SHELLFOLDERS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-STORAGE-EXPORTS-EXTERNAL-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-STORAGE-EXPORTS-INTERNAL-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-IDENTITY-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-INTERNAL-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-UNLOCK-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-BASE-UTIL-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CALENDAR-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L2-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DEBUG-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DELAYLOAD-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-ERRORHANDLING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FIBERS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-HEAP-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-INTERLOCKED-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-IO-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-LEGACY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LIBRARYLOADER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-OBSOLETE-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALREGISTRY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-MARSHAL-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-MEMORY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSENVIRONMENT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTHREADS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTHREADS-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTOPOLOGY-OBSOLETE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PSM-APPNOTIFY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REALTIME-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRY-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-RTLSUPPORT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SHUTDOWN-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSINFO-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSINFO-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-TOOLHELP-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-VERSION-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-VERSION-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-VERSIONANSI-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERRORPRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-PROPERTYSETPRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-PROPERTYSETPRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-REGISTRATION-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-COREUI-SECRUNTIME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DEVICES-QUERY-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-ADVAPI32-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-ADVAPI32-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-KERNEL32-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-NORMALIZ-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-OLE32-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-SHELL32-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-SHLWAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-SHLWAPI-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-SHLWAPI-L2-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-USER32-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-VERSION-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DX-D3DKMT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DX-D3DKMT-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-LEGACY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-TDH-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTLOG-LEGACY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-GDI-DPIINFO-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-MM-JOYSTICK-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-MM-MISC-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-MM-MISC-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-MM-MME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-MM-TIME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-NTUSER-IE-MESSAGE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-NTUSER-SYSPARAMS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-OLE32-IE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-POWER-SETTING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-CLIPBOARD-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-SYNCH-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-WINDOW-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-WINEVENT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-OLE32-CLIPBOARD-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-ACCESSHLPR-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-ACTIVEDIRECTORYCLIENT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-ACTIVEDIRECTORYCLIENT-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-BASE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CREDENTIALS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CREDENTIALS-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CRYPTOAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-GROUPPOLICY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LSALOOKUP-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LSALOOKUP-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LSALOOKUP-L2-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LSAPOLICY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-PROVIDER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-SDDLPARSECOND-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-WINSVC-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-COMHELPERS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-OBSOLETE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-STREAM-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-STREAM-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SYSINFO-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-THREAD-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-UNICODEANSI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHELL-SHDIRECTORY-L1-1-0.DLL
DEVICELOCKHELPERS.DLL
EMCLIENT.DLL
EXT-MS-MF-PAL-L2-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-APPCHROMEAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-APPMODEL-PLM-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-APPMODEL-VEVENTDISPATCHER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-DCOMP-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-ORIENTATION-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-PHONEINFO-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-SHELLCHROMEAPI-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-EVENTINGCONTROLLER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-MSI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-NPUSERNAME-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-NTMARTA-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-PSM-APP-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-REGISTRY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-SAFER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPCOMPAT-APPHELP-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-DEPLOYMENT-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-STATE-EXT-L1-2-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-USERCONTEXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-VIEWSCALEFACTOR-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPXDEPLOYMENTCLIENT-APPXDEPLOY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPXDEPLOYMENTCLIENT-APPXDEPLOYONECORE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-AUDIOCORE-PAL-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-AUTHZ-CONTEXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-AUTHZ-REMOTE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-CLBCATQ-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-COML2-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-OLE32-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-OLE32-L1-1-3.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-PSMREGISTER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-SUSPENDRESILIENCY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-REMOTE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DEVMGMT-POLICY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DOMAINJOIN-NETJOIN-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DWMAPIDXGI-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-EDPUTIL-POLICY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-FAMILYSAFETY-CHILDACCOUNT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-FECLIENT-ENCRYPTEDFILE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-FIREWALLAPI-WEBPROXY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DC-CREATE-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DC-L1-2-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DEVCAPS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DRAW-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DRAW-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-FONT-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-FONT-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-METAFILE-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-PATH-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-RENDER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GLOBALIZATION-INPUT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GPAPI-GROUPPOLICY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-APPCOMPAT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-DATETIME-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-ERRORHANDLING-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-FILE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-LOCALIZATION-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-PACKAGE-CURRENT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-PACKAGE-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-QUIRKS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-QUIRKS-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-REGISTRY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-SIDEBYSIDE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-WINDOWSERRORREPORTING-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-WINDOWSERRORREPORTING-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNELBASE-PROCESSTHREAD-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-MININPUT-INPUTHOST-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-MPR-MULTIPLEPROVIDERROUTER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-MRMCORER-ENVIRONMENT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-MRMCORER-RESMANAGER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTDSAPI-ACTIVEDIRECTORYCLIENT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTDSAPI-ACTIVEDIRECTORYCLIENT-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-DC-ACCESS-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-DIALOGBOX-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-DIALOGBOX-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-DRAW-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-DRAW-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-GUI-L1-3-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-KEYBOARD-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-KEYBOARD-L1-2-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MENU-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MENU-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MESSAGE-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MESSAGE-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MISC-L1-3-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MISC-L1-5-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MOUSE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-PRIVATE-L1-2-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-RECTANGLE-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-ROTATIONMANAGER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-SYNCH-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-UICONTEXT-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-WINDOW-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-WINDOW-L1-1-3.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-WINDOWCLASS-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-WINDOWCLASS-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-WINDOWSTATION-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-OLE32-BINDCTX-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-OLE32-IE-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-OLE32-OLEAUTOMATION-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-PROFILE-EXTENDER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-PROFILE-LOAD-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-PROFILE-USERENV-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-PROFILE-USERENV-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RPC-SSL-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-GDI-DEVCAPS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-GDI-OBJECT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-GDI-RGN-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-GDI-RGN-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-MINUSER-PRIVATE-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-CURSOR-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-DC-ACCESS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-DPI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-IAM-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-INTEGRATION-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-SYNCH-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-SYSCOLORS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-SYSPARAMS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-WINDOW-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECUR32-TRANSLATENAME-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CAPAUTHZ-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CHAMBERS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CREDUI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-EFS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-EFSWRT-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SESSION-USERMGR-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SESSION-USERTOKEN-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SESSION-WINSTA-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SESSION-WTSAPI32-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SETUPAPI-INF-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SHELL-DIRECTORY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SHELL-EXPORTS-INTERNAL-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SHELL-KNOWNFOLDEREXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SHELL-PROPSYS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SHELL-SETTINGSYNC-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SHELL-SHELL32-L1-2-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SHELL-SHLWAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SHELL32-SHELLCOM-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SXS-OLEAUTOMATION-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-UI-VIEWMANAGEMENT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-USP10-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WER-UI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WER-XBOX-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WINRT-STORAGE-FILEEXPLORER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WINRT-STORAGE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WINRT-STORAGE-REMOVABLE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WLAN-ONEXUI-L1-1-0.DLL
IESHIMS.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-STATE-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PSM-KEY-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRY-L2-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-POWER-BASE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CAPABILITY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-REGISTRY-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHLWAPI-IE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHLWAPI-WINRT-STORAGE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHLWAPI-WINRT-STORAGE-L1-1-1.DLL
```

here is this just in case it is needed

[image: screen shot]

so now I am at the point where I tried looking up the files missing and read I should install, "Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015"

but I have it already installed along with 2010 and every version up

I have Visual studios 2015 enterprise installed with everything with it

SO now I am just lost on what to do now

Comment: The question hardly directly relates to Qt Creator itself but to environment it provides: the way you set up the project. I would try to debug execute the process from Visual Studio and when the error hit provide the path to source code. https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=visual%20studio%20debug%20executable

Comment: @AlexanderVX I don't really know how to debug but I can try it

Comment: Are you sure you don't just need to add the path to your dlls, for example on my development PC I can run my Qt executables in Qt Creator (since it sets up its path environment), however if I run the executable stand-alone it fails. So I have added `C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\mingw492_32\bin` to my path to make it work. You probably need to add a similar path for your Qt dlls. Are you using mingw (this is a 32-bit compiler, which might be your 32/64bit issue) or the msvc compiler in your Qt?

Comment: @code_fodder , doing what you said worked!

Comment: Ok cool. I'll add it as an "answer" but with the caveat that this is not really how you deploy an executable. I'll add some notes/links on how you can do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this on your development PC by adding the path to your qt bin directory. For example for mingw it might be somthing like:

`C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\mingw492_32\bin`

For MSVC it will be a little different (don't have an MSVC install handy so can't remember the path.

**Note** You should only really use this for your development PC, but if you want to create a "deployable" version (i.e. copy it to different PCs) then you will need to copy all the dll's that your project uses and put them into the same folder as your executable.

For example: You need to copy the required dll's from here (using mingw as an example):

`C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\mingw492_32\bin`

Into the folder where your executable lives (again just an example):

`D:\software\build-qtGuiTestApp-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Release\release`

You can copy the dll's that are shown in your dependancy walker for a start. For MSVC you might want your deployment to actually install msvc redest to save you copying the dll's - but then you need to ensure the path is all setup etc...

This link has some more good information with lots of various compiler specific notes: [here](http://qt.developpez.com/doc/4.7/deployment-windows/)

**Note 2** Infact see this question of mine for usage (look at mikes answer as well) of windeployqt [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36630830/windeployqt-misses-some-of-the-libraries-and-gets-others-that-are-not-required)