# The procedure entry point couldn't be located in the dynamic link library

Tags: c++, qt

Can't run builded exe file from windows explorer. But from qt creator exe runs normally. 
Programm created as Qt Creater Application on C++ language, Qt Creator Version : 4.0.2.

When trying to run the following error occurs:
[image]

Comment: Most likely `libstdc++-6.dll` is the wrong version. Meaning you have more than 1 `libstdc++-6.dll` installed on your PC.

Comment: Try using `windeployqt`, this can help you deploying your application quickly (instead of manually copying DLL files). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36630830/2666212), basically you need to use `--compiler-runtime` switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy `libstdc++-6.dll` from the folder where Qt is intalled (e.g., `C:\Qt\mingw492_32\bin`) to the folder where you want to start your `.exe` file.

For More information, see [Creating the Application Package](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html#creating-the-application-package).

Comment: Stackoverflow is an [English-only website](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange). Please use English in your posts. If this is not applicable for you, you can use [ru.stackoverflow.com](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/). Users reading answers here wouldn't expect to see each answer in a different language.